# How to identify what service is causing high cpu usage for svchost.exe

Tags: windows-7, cpu

About twice a day svchost.exe uses 50% CPU for more 20-40 minutes. If I kill the process it starts again. Is there a way to identify what service is causing this without disabling services one by one? The virus scanner is scheduled for other time and is not reporting that it would be scanning.
Switched off real time scanning in antivirus app and didn't help.

Edit:
Turns out it was the Windows update service. I suspect this is Microsoft's revenge for not upgrading to Windows 10 because seems to be related with the popup asking me to install W10.